# read txt file and then delete it in a windows service c#

Tags: c#, json, windows, file, service

I have made a windows service in C#, what this service does is read a text file and convert it to json, but what I want to know is how can I delete that txt file once converted to json, it doesn't allow me to delete it because I get this log, "The process cannot access the file 'C:\API\inbox\13203530500100000060800712202231100.TXT' because it is being used by another process."

I am using the following to get the txt of the folder:

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(rutaRaiz, "*.txt");

thanks for the support,

use the **File.Delete(item)** to delete the txt but it gave me error:
, "The process cannot access the file 'C:\API\inbox\13203530500100000060800712202231100.TXT' because it is being used by another process."

Comment: Inbox sounds like there is a another process that puts something in there that you then collect. Presumably the other process isn't ready yet with writing the file. Or the problem is yourself. For converting the file you need to open that file. That code is more prone to the problem you describe and you should show that.

Comment: You've show how you're getting the file names, but not how you're opening the file.  Please post additional code so we can see how it's being opened

Comment: Hello friends, I already found the solution to my problem, thanks